# How to create a custom Administrator in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I am using Alfresco 6.2. I want to create an Administrator who is not allowed to create content? What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

User’s role determines what they can and cannot do in a site. Each role has a default set of permissions. You can choose the roles based on your requirement.

- Managers have full rights to all site content - what they have
  created themselves and what other site members have created.
- Collaborators have full rights to the site content that they own;
  they have rights to edit but not delete content created by other site
  members.
- Contributors have full rights to the site content that they own; they
  cannot edit or delete content created by other site members.
- Consumers have view-only rights in a site: they cannot create their
  own content.
  Coordinator - has full rights to all content - what they
  have created themselves and what others have created.
- Editor - has rights to edit file properties and check files in and
  out; they cannot create their own content.

You can then configure custom permissions (could also be referred to as custom roles). Please follow this link for Custom [Permissions](https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/latest/develop/repo-ext-points/permissions/).

Comment: When I create this particular role I want this Admin to Access other pages like AdminTools , Repository and other Admin specific pages. How can I make it achievable to this role?

Comment: Then you have to create a custom role please go through the custom permissions link in the original answer.